# Restarting application pool using angular

Tags: c#, angular, iis, angular-material

Is there any way we can Recycle an application pool (in IIS) from angular UI (on button click)?
We can achieve this using dotnet, but unable find a way to implement that using angular.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The obvious way would be that your Angular app would call a dotnet endpoint to do this. I do have to ask though - why do you want to recycle the application pool frequently enough that it's worth building a UI for it?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! for the response.
We have a UI app that maintains the configuration details related to APIs. So whenever the configurations are updated, the deployment team will reset the application pool manually. Now they want it from UI on button click to happen instead of logging into ISS to reset app pool.

Comment: Do we need to consider if anything related to versioning of IIS while handling this reset functionality from c# api?

Comment: No, if you get any problems during this process, please come to discuss.